# SQLite3 Select Statement Query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following sqlite3 table, BookAuthor:

```
BookID    AuthorID
B13       A02
B13       A67
B13       A13
B02       A02
B02       A67
B45       A02
B45       A13
B33       A02
```

And want to produce this one:

```
Author1  Author2 NumCoAuthored
A02      A67     2
A02      A13     2
A67      A13     1
```

I need help writing the sql select statement. I don't even know where to start or if it's possible.

Kindly note that the data set is really large (more than 10 GB) and I'm guessing i might have to do it in chunk sizes.

So maybe I should order by AuthorID and do it each author at a time with every other Author?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
SELECT
  BA1.authorID AS Author1
  , BA2.authorID AS Author2
  , COUNT(BA1.bookID) NumCoAuthored
FROM BookAuthor BA1
JOIN BookAuthor BA2
  ON BA1.bookID = BA2.bookID
  AND BA1.authorID < BA2.authorID
GROUP BY BA1.authorID, BA2.authorID
```

See it in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/f2ed3a/1).

Please comment if and as this requrires adjustment / further detail.

Comment: This works perfectly and I can use the logic behind it to figure out the rest! thank you so much :) I guess I didn't realise that you can compare texts authorID < authorID the way you did. This is new to me :) Thanks again!